# PHP not iterating through nested JSON properly

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to loop through a JSON Object `(DATA)` containing three nested JSON Objects (`NEWUSERS`,`NEWUSERDATA`,`NEWRELATIONS`), using a switch function to choose the appropriate function for a MySQL insert. Each function housed in the switch is called once as I loop through the keys, but they ALL seem to only ever receive the `NEWRELATIONS` object. Consequently, the functions fail with the exception of `insertNewTestRelations`, the function intended to receive the `NEWRELATIONS` object. I think the answer must be staring me in the face, but can anybody think why the JSON object is being reused?

Reading and iterating JSON

```
$json=json_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'],true);
$data=$json['DATA'];

foreach($data as $key=>$json_obj){
    $result=null;
    $result=$db->insertNewSwitch($key,$json_obj,$last_sync);

    $response[$key.":errors"]=$result['errors'];
    $response[$key.":successes"]=$result['successes'];

}
```

Switch function

```
public function insertNewSwitch($key,$json_obj,$last_sync){
    $result;
    if($key="NEWUSERS"){
        $result=$this->insertNewTestUsers($json_obj,$last_sync,$key);
    }

    if($key="NEWUSERDATA"){
        $result=$this->insertNewTestUserdata($json_obj,$last_sync,$key);
    }

    if($key="NEWRELATIONS"){
        $result=$this->insertNewTestRelations($json_obj,$last_sync,$key);
    }


    return $result;
}
```

Comment: One issue is that your if statements are **assigning** value rather than **comparing** values: `if($key="NEWUSERS"){` should be `if($key == "NEWUSERS"){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using else in your logical operator for the switch, and also double equals for comparisons

```
public function insertNewSwitch($key,$json_obj,$last_sync){
    $result;
    if($key=="NEWUSERS"){
        $result=$this->insertNewTestUsers($json_obj,$last_sync,$key);
    }

     else if($key=="NEWUSERDATA"){
        $result=$this->insertNewTestUserdata($json_obj,$last_sync,$key);
    }

    else if($key=="NEWRELATIONS"){
        $result=$this->insertNewTestRelations($json_obj,$last_sync,$key);
    }


    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Ah, staring me right in the face after all. Thanks for helping me in a moment of madness.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `=` not `==`. This is most likely your problem.
Because you are assigning the values, it will evaluate to true each time, so each statement will be entered.